# Infinite loop while reading file

Tags: c#, infinite-loop, readfile

I get a random line from file:

```
using (FileStream ifs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ifs, Encoding)) {
        long lastPos = ifs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        long rndPos = 0;
          do {
              rndPos = (long)(Random.NextDouble() * lastPos);// Random is property
              ifs.Seek(rndPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
              sr.ReadLine();
              line = sr.ReadLine();
          } while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));
    }
}
```

But sometimes it turns out that the line is always null and loop is infinite. Please, where am I wrong?

This function is called 1000 times (for example). The first 100 calls are successful, but then the position of the main stream is the last position, and seek not worked.

ps: I want to get a random position in the file. Then read through the line on which this position to the end and return as result the following line. It is the fastest algorithm to obtain a random string of a large file in a loop. And yes, I know that this function never returns the first row.

Comment: `while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));` does look like a dangerous way to go.. have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745934/read-random-line-from-a-file-c-sharp

Comment: Can you please explain what you expect from your code? Randomly reading values from a file do not guarantee your loop to terminate irrespective of your condition on the string...

Comment: I would assume when the file is empty you would never find a row and will be searching for any random content

Comment: ... or if there's only a single line in the file. Your code would *never* return the first line of the file, because you always read two lines.

Comment: Najzero, this solution does not fit, I call this many times.

Comment: Boas Enkler, Jon Skeet, thank you, I know.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov, I want to get a random position in the file. Then read through the line on which this position to the end and return as result the following line. It is the fastest algorithm to obtain a random string of a large file in a loop. And yes, I know that this function never returns the first row.

Comment: Can you show code for "Random is property" - any chance that it looks like `get { return new Random(0);}` ?

Comment: just put a breakpoint when you get in an infinite loop and _observe_ why it is looping infinitely.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, no.`public static Random Random = new Random();`

Comment: @Eren Ersönmez, done. No ideas.

Comment: The biggest flaw here is using both the `StreamReader` and underlying stream at the same time.

Comment: @leppie, I'd vote for "biggest flaw is trying to read string from the middle byte of multibyte UTF8 characters, or odd byte of UTF16".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: That too, but messing around with the position of a stream while using a reader, is just looking for problems.

Comment: My problem: this function is called 1000 times (for example). The first 100 calls are successful, but then the position of the main stream is the last position, and seek not worked.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov in my case it is the best choice.

Comment: This would have all been handy to know **in the question** whereas now, this is becoming a multi-book adventure...

Answer (score 0):

Well if the line is null, and your condition says string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line), it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Why line is null? =) File is not empty, random is realy random every time. May be some feature of the stream?

Comment: @Slovo Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450263/c-sharp-streamreader-readline-does-not-work-properly

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ReturnRandomLine(string path, ref Random r)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    string randomLine = String.Empty;
    int randomLineNumber;

    do
    {
        randomLineNumber = r.Next(0, lines.Length - 1);
        randomLine = lines[randomLineNumber];
    } while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(randomLine));

    return @"Line #" + randomLineNumber + " " + randomLine;
}
```

Comment: The file is too large for `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);`